# Next.js with multer picture upload

Tags: reactjs, next.js, multer

I am trying to upload a single picture to next.js api using multer middleware but it not being uploaded. Using next.js 13 and app router.

Here's what I tried:

```
  "use client"
  import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
  import axios from 'axios'
  import { useMutation } from 'react-query'

  const Upload: React.FC = () => {
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
    const [uploading, setUploading] = useState(false);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

    const fileInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    const mutation = useMutation( async(file: File) => {    
      const data = new FormData()
      data.append('file', file)

      for (let [key, value] of data.entries()) {
        console.log(key, value);
      }

      axios.post('/api/uploader', data, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      }).then(res => {
        setMessage(JSON.stringify(res.data.message, null, 2));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res?.data, null, 2));
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log('err', err);
        setMessage('Error: ');
      });
    })


    const handleFileChange = async(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      const uploadedFile = e.target.files ? e.target.files[0] : null;
      setSelectedFile(uploadedFile);    
    };

    const handleUpload = () => {
      setUploading(true); 
      if (selectedFile) {
        mutation.mutate(selectedFile)
      }
      setUploading(false);
    }

    return (
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
        <div className="w-full max-w-md px-8 py-6 mx-auto bg-white rounded shadow-md">
          <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold text-center text-gray-700">Upload File</h2>
          <div className="flex flex-col mt-4">
            <input
              type="file"
              accept=".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.png"
              ref={fileInputRef}
              onChange={handleFileChange}
              className="hidden"
            />
            <button
              onClick={() => fileInputRef.current?.click()}
              className="px-4 py-2 text-white bg-blue-600 rounded hover:bg-blue-700 focus:outline-none"
            >
              Select File
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={handleUpload}
              className="px-4 py-2 mt-3 text-white bg-green-600 rounded hover:bg-green-700 focus:outline-none"
            >
              Upload File
            </button>
            <p className="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-600">
              {selectedFile ? `Selected file: ${selectedFile.name}` : 'No file selected'}
            </p>
            <p className="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-600">
              {message && `Server Message: ${message}`}
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };

  export default Upload;
```

In Middleware.ts:

```
    import multer from "multer";
    import { ulid } from 'ulid'


    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req: any, file: any, cb: any) {
        cb(null, "public/uploads");
      },
      filename: function (req: any, file: any, cb: any) {
        cb(null, ulid() + "-" + file.originalname);
      },
    });

    const fileFilter = (req: any, file: any, cb: any) => {
      if (
        file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" 
        || file.mimetype === "image/png" 
        || file.mimetype === "image/jpg"
      ) {
        cb(null, true);
      } else cb(null, false);
    };

    const multerUpload = multer({
      storage,
      limits: { fieldSize: 1024 * 1024 },
      fileFilter,
    });

    export {multerUpload};
```

and finally in route

```
            import { createEdgeRouter } from "next-connect";
            import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
            import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
            import { multerUpload } from "@/utils/middleware";


            interface MulterFile {
                path: string;
                originalname: string;
            }

            interface NextRequestWithFile extends NextRequest {
                file?: MulterFile;
            }
            const router = createEdgeRouter<NextRequestWithFile, { params?: unknown }>();
            // router.use(multerUpload.any());
            router.use(multerUpload.single("file"));

            router.post(async (req) => {
                console.log('req.file:',req.file);  // THIS LOGS UNDEFINED
                return NextResponse.json({message: "File uploaded"});
            })

            export async function POST(request: NextRequest, ctx: { params?: unknown }) {
            return router.run(request, ctx);
            }
```

When I try logging the file, it is undefined, also I cannot find any examples online of next.js 13 with multer. Is this a configuration problem or multer is not compatible with next 13?